# Unvisited nodes in Dijkstra's algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, shortest-path

In the priority queue implementation of Dijkstra's Algorithm we remove the node at the top, mark it as visited and update the distance values of all the vertices adjacent to the top.

In doing so do we need to check whether the vertices adjacent to the top have already been visited or do we update it for all the vertices irrespective of if they have been visited or not?

Comment: If there are no edges with negative weight in the graph, the algorithm should work correctly either way. And if there are some, it doesn't work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Are you interested in knowing only a node's *reachability* or in knowing the *reachability along with the minimum distance*?

- For **only reachability**, do not update it once marked visited.
- For <sup>†</sup>**reachability and minimum distance**, if the distance is less than the (*current value in the node + the cost to reach the neighbor node from current node*), update it. Otherwise leave it as it is.

---

<sup><sup>†</sup> One scenario which falls in this case is when a robot tries to find the quickest path to some place from its current location.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Suppose current node removed from priority queue is `cur` then we need to check that from cur node we can find any edge that can reduce distance of any adjacency node then we need to update the distance.

Note that when node is removed from priority queue that means we have already found the minimum distance for that node from the source vertex.I think you are confused a bit, so go over the algorithm once again.

Answer (score 0):

It is implementation dependent.

The fact is, [Dijkstra's Algorithm original pape](http://www-m3.ma.tum.de/foswiki/pub/MN0506/WebHome/dijkstra.pdf)r didn't even mention heap - but it processed only edges that are connected to an unvisited node (so check only the unvisited ones), some implementations (such as the one represented in C.L.R.S) update all nodes connected to the processed node.

Relevant quote from dijkstra's original paper:

> the path of minimum length from P is known (set A) and others (sets
> B,C)... Consider all branches connecting the node just transfeired to
> set A with nodes  in sets B or C

The above quote specifically considers only updating nodes which were never discovered yet.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no problem in both the cases**(Provided there is neg-weight cycle which is the pre-condition for applying dijkstra). But we generally remove redundancy for efficient code and that's why an already visited node is not updated as it is relaxed already. We check it this way

```
if(dist == initial distance) then only apply a step

otherwise leave it...(pop and then go to next node in priority queue)
```

Hope this helps. Now if you ignore this one then no problem..no complexity changes but redundant check for relaxatation operation occurs.